# javascript console.log not printing correct values

Tags: javascript

I have following js codes:

```
var a = {x:1, y:2};
console.log(a);
console.log(a.x);
a.x = 0;
console.log(a);
console.log(a.x);
```

Outputs (in firefox, chrome):

```
Object x: 0 y: 2
1
Object x: 0 y: 2
0
```

Why is a.x 0 in first console.log? It is not assigned to 0 yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: When I run that code in my Chrome console I get the correct results.